# How to include host variables inside raw adhoc commands (to be run on the guest)?

Tags: ansible

For example, if the following variable is defined on the Ansible host:

```
export TEST=new_dir
```

How can that variable be added to an adhoc `-m raw` command:

```
ansible -m raw -a 'mkdir /home/user/$TEST'
```

Such that Ansible host command runs `mkdir /home/user/new_dir` on the guest machine?

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help of `env` lookup:

```
ansible -m raw -a 'mkdir /home/user/{{ lookup("env","TEST") }}'
```